# Import Oracle 11g Database .dmp file to Oracle 11g Instant Client (on Mac OSX Mavericks)

Tags: macos, oracle, import, oracle11g, osx-mavericks

I have a **.dmp** file that I would like to **import** into an **11g Oracle Instant Client** environment I have set up on on my **Mac** (Mavericks). How can I do this? Thanks!

note: I also have the the full oracle 11g installed on a Windows 8 PC, so I could export data from there if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Instant Client is not a database.  You can't "import" into it.  It is just the client components to access the database.

Comment: oh, so it would only let me access a database on another machine?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  If you want to import a dmp file, you need to execute either the IMP or IMPDP commands (depending if file was created with EXP or EXPDP ).

Comment: Okay, thanks. What I am trying to do is hook up a WebSphere liberty profile to an Oracle 11g database natively on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible.
You need to install a database. For development purposes you can install Oracle XE

Unfortunatelly is not avaible for MacOS, you would need a Linux or Win

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen

Answer (score 0):

As OldDeveloper said, "Instant Client is not a database. You can't "import" into it. It is just the client components to access the database."